# How to dynamically pass codeUri in SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I am trying to deploy lambda having a zip(contains jar file). Now if the static value of the artifact in `CodeUri` is provided, it works fine but the problem is that the artifact is not static in nature i.e the version of the jar file (along with its name ex: **abc-<1.x.x>-prod.jar**) will change whenever their is new build.

So, I want to pass the artifact name in `CodeUri` as dynamic value rather than static value.
I had tried splitting `Bucket`, `Key` & pass the value as parameter but it fails saying **NoSuchKey** while deployment.

**Edit: Adding Sample Template**

```
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: engine-service

Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Default: ""
  SecurityGroupIds:
    Type: String
    Default: ""
  SubnetIds1:
    Type: String
    Default: ""
  SubnetIds2:
    Type: String
    Default: ""
  DBSubnetGroupName:
    Type: String
    Default: ""
  RDSSecret:
    Type: String
    Default: ""
  RDSInstance:
    Type: String
    Default: ""
  API:
    Type: String
    Default: ""

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 120

Resources:
  TranslationEngineLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub "translation-engine-service-${Environment}"
      CodeUri: target/abc-**1.0.0-SNAPSHOT**-prod.jar
      Handler: com.abc.Main
      Runtime: java11
      MemorySize: 1024
      Environment:
        Variables:
          BUCKET_NAME: "abc-dummy"
          DB_SECRET: "abc-dummy"
          FUNCTION_NAME: TranslateFunction
          SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: db
          TEXT_EXTRACT_LAMBDA: !Sub arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:text-extract-service-${Environment}
          TRANSLATE_OPTION: AWS
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: 
          - !Ref SecurityGroupIds
        SubnetIds: 
          - !Ref SubnetIds1
          - !Ref SubnetIds2
      Policies:
        - AWSLambda_FullAccess
        - AmazonEC2FullAccess
        - SecretsManagerReadWrite
        - AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
        - AmazonRDSFullAccess

  TranslationEngineLambdaInvoke:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      FunctionName: !GetAtt "TranslationEngineLambda.Arn"
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Join  ['', ['arn:aws:execute-api:MyRegion:MyAccountNumber:', Fn::ImportValue: !Ref API, '/*/POST/language-translator/v1/translate']]

Outputs:
  TranslationEngineLambda:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt TranslationEngineLambda.Arn
  TranslationEngineLambdaIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt TranslationEngineLambdaRole.Arn`
```

Comment: Can you add your current template to the question?

Comment: @stijndepestel Added the template in question.

Answer (score -1):

Your question encompasses a few things.

First, if you're using `CodeUri` as you're doing in the template with a relative URL, AWS SAM will use that path to search from the directory in which the template resides to find the required files. If you're using Bucket/Key, AWS SAM will look in S3 to the specified Bucket and search for the Key. This is of course an entirely different way of working and assumes that you've already uploaded the artefact to that location yourself. You've presumably not done this, which results in the `NoSuchKey` error.

One of the more useful things about AWS SAM is that you can not only use it to deploy your code, but you can also use it to build your artefacts themselves. In that case, you have to point your `CodeUri` to the root of the folder in which your Lambda function code resides. AWS SAM will then - in the build step - create the necessary artefact (be it a jar of a zip). During the deployment, it will upload those artefacts to S3, update the `CodeUri`s to reflect this and deploy the CloudFormation stack.

I don't think you can use CloudFormation parameters (with `!Sub`, `!Join` or similar) when using a relative `CodeUri` URL since the parameters are only interpreted in the cloud, and not during the AWS SAM build or package steps. So if you do not want to rely on AWS SAM to build your artefacts, you're probably better of also uploading them yourself.